# Breakpoint set with IntelliJ not working in premain of remote custom java agent

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, agent

I've started to implement a simple Java agent that does some instrumentation before a class is loaded by JVM. The thing is I need to do some debugging on this agent, but what I tried so far had failed( I tried to remote debug the agent but it's not working)

I use IntelliJ and Maven( to generate the .jar agent).

So my question:Is there any trick to remote debug a simple java agent?

Comment: You can't just set a break point in your agent source code?

Comment: I can set a break point but the execution doesn't stop when the break point is reached.

Comment: did  you  add  logging  statements  to  verify  that  code is executing?

Comment: Yes I did! The code is executing but it doesn't break! Because I use mvn to package the agent I also made sure maven will compile with debug option set true. Then I got back into IntelliJ and set-up a remote debug for the agent! After that I started the remote debug. Last I executed the application which is instrumented by the agent.

Comment: Faced same problem. I was unable to stop at breakpoints, but at the same time I got messages saying I connected to the target VM. Spent quite a time, but solved the problem by putting -agentlib:jdwp option before -javaagent: ... So it appears, order matters :)

Comment: @TimofeiDavydik Thanks a lot for this. This is the correct solution, the order matters quite a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it turns out I have a project that demos Java instrumentation, which I have tested out debugging in IntelliJ. Breakpoints work. You can use it as a reference.

https://github.com/noahlz/weaver-demo

Sample run/debug configuration from IntelliJ

[image: Agent App Run/Debug]

Also, if you are debugging remotely, the premain might be executing before you can attach to the debugger. Try changing `suspend=n` to `suspend=y` in the debug command you are passing to the JVM running the agent code. That way, it will wait until you connect with IntelliJ before proceeding.

Comment: "unless you add the agent library to the application's JAR dependencies" - exactly what I did in my aforementioned demo application on GitHub: https://github.com/noahlz/weaver-demo/blob/master/pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

For people using VSCode, I just figured out that breakpoints in premain work for me if I use the integratedTerminal, and that they DONT WORK if I use internalConsole!!!

[image]

`"java.debug.settings.console": "integratedTerminal"`