# Intellij break point not working.

Tags: java, maven, intellij-12

I've a maven project deployed in jetty 9 server.
I'm running jetty server with following options.

```
java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 -jar /home/shwetanka/tools/jetty-distribution-9.2.3.v20140905/start.jar
```

I've configured a remote configuration with [image: idea debug dialog]

When I start debugger. It says

> Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:5005', transport:
>   'socket'

But breakpoint remains in 'enabled' state(without any check mark) and doesn't stop on reaching the break point. I tried making the project again but it says all classes are up to date. nothing to reload. I tried restarting idea and also invalidating the cache. Nothing seems to be working. How do I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the solution mentioned at [Breakpoint set with IntelliJ not working in premain of remote custom java agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105615/breakpoint-set-with-intellij-not-working-in-premain-of-remote-custom-java-agent).

Alternately, you might try *suspend=y* instead of *suspend=n*

This worked for me on the same problem.
Cheers!